# How to add a custom mapboxgl.js icontrol to react component?

Tags: reactjs, mapbox-gl-js, icontrol

I am having trouble to add a mapbox custom `icontrol` in react.

I found an example/approach with google maps [here](https://github.com/tomchentw/react-google-maps/issues/818) but I cannot find the equivalent with mapbox.

Specifically, I need to render a button on the map component which when clicked would open a menu drawer from the right side of the page

***just to clarify the drawer would cover the entire height of the view

```
div.drawer { height: 100vh; width 15vw;` }
```